# Delete query - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

If I have a table such as:

```
     name1       |    name2     |    id     |
+----------------+--------------+-----------+
| A              | E            | 1         |
| A              | F            | 1         |
| B              | G            | 1         |
| C              | H            | 1         |
| D              | I            | 1         |
| A              | J            | 2         |
| B              | K            | 2         |
| C              | L            | 2         |
| D              | M            | 2         |
| A              | N            | 2         |
```

what I need is that delete all rows of id which contain name2 = E

If I do:

```
delete from table where name2 = E
```

It only gives me this

```
     name1       |    name2     |    id     |
+----------------+--------------+-----------+
| A              | F            | 1         |
| B              | G            | 1         |
| C              | H            | 1         |
| D              | I            | 1         |
| A              | J            | 2         |
| B              | K            | 2         |
| C              | L            | 2         |
| D              | M            | 2         |
| A              | N            | 2         |
```

The result I want is :

```
     name1       |    name2     |    id     |
+----------------+--------------+-----------+
| A              | J            | 2         |
| B              | K            | 2         |
| C              | L            | 2         |
| D              | M            | 2         |
| A              | N            | 2         |
```

Which query should I use?

Comment: Huh? You have conflicting requirements in your question. You want to delete all rows which contain name2=E, yet the table under your desired results has deleted F,G,H, and I. You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
delete t
    from table t join
         table t2
         on t.id = t2.id and t2.name2 = 'E';
```

This deletes all rows from the table that share an id with a row whose `name2` is `'E'`.

In most other databases, you could write:

```
delete t from table t
    where t.id in (select t2.id from table t2 where t2.name2 = 'E');
```

Or something similar using `exists`.  Unfortunately, MySQL does not allow this syntax because the subquery references the table being modified.  There is a hack:

```
delete t from table t
    where t.id in (select id from (select t2.id from table t2 where t2.name2 = 'E') t);
```

I prefer the version with the `join`.

For a `select`, I would do:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.id in (select t2.id from table t2 where t2.name2 = 'E');
```

or:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.name2 = 'E' and t2.id = t.id);
```

Comment: Up for the MySQL subquery restriction.

Comment: If I would like to do select instead of delete, what should I do? : )

Comment: As it stands right now the question asks about a single table. Did it previously mention two tables?